# Math Alignment Environments ConTeXt

Tags: context

My original question was a bit broader than this one but I was told it was hard to understand so I'm rewriting it to be more concrete.

Let's say I've got the following code

```
\starttabulate[|l|l|]
    \NC \|$\text{eq}_1 = 250$\|
        \NC \|$\text{eq}_2 = 250$\|
    \NC\NR
    \NC \|$\text{eq}_3 = 4$\|
        \NC \|{\hsize=0.2\hsize \startformula\startalign\NC \text{eq}_4 \NC = \lfloor \frac{n_0}{\beta_1} \rfloor + 2 \NR \NC\NC = 160.5 \stopalign\stopformula}\|
    \NC\NR
\stoptabulate
```

When I run it in ConTeXt I get the following table.

[image]

I've inserted vertical rules to show the ends of the columns.

I want to ask how I can

1. Left/Right align eq_4
2. Align the first line in eq_4 with eq_3 (so that they're on the same baseline)
3. Get the vertical box housing eq_4 to take on the width of its content (without fiddling around with hsize)

What I've tried so far to achieve left alignment is to add the option `[m=2,distance=5em plus 1fil]` in front of `\startalign` as recommended by this manual https://dl.contextgarden.net/myway/mathalign.pdf, but that knocked eq_4 out of its column, as you can see in this image

[image]

I managed to get the bottom of the eq_4 to align with eq_3 by adding the option `[location=bottom]` but `[location=top]` gives me an extra line above eq_4 as seen here

[image]

I tried adding a `\vskip-\baselineskip` in every place between the two `\NC`'s to try and move eq_4 up, but I kept getting an error message saying I'd "confused [ConTeXt's] parser".

And I haven't been able to get 3. (getting the vertical box to to on the natural width of the equation) to work except by manually adjusting `\hsize`.

When I'm using these built in environments, a lot of times it feels like I'm shooting in the dark, hoping to hit something. I'm hoping to change that by better understanding how these environments work. To that end, can someone explain how the `\startformula` and `\startalign` environments work, i.e., how they determine the size of the vertical box that houses the equation, the glue inside that box, etc.

Thanks and I apologize if my previous question was hard to understand.

Answer (score 3):

It is still not really clear to me what you are after. Do you really need to use a table? Here is just using align:

```
\starttext

\samplefile{knuthmath}

\startformula
  \startalign[n=2,m=2,distance=4em]
    \NC \mathrm{eq}_1 \EQ 250 \NC \mathrm{eq}_2 \EQ 250                                     \NR
    \NC \mathrm{eq}_3 \EQ 4   \NC \mathrm{eq}_4 \EQ \lfloor \frac{n_0}{\beta_1} \rfloor + 2 \NR
    \NC               \NC     \NC               \EQ 160.5                                   \NR          
  \stopalign
\stopformula

\samplefile{knuthmath}

\stoptext
```

Output:

[image: formulas]

Comment: Thanks, the layout is fine. I need a table because I feel it will scale better.  Are you aware of how to make it work with the table environment?

Comment: I suggest that you ask a new question showing that situation that really needs a table (you can link to this one). Because if we change the real question here all the time, it will never converge.